# Data Model Share in Administrations Micro Service

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-ee, web-applications, microservices

Can any one please help to understand better.

We are developing an application using Micro Service Architecture Now we have different structure.

Based on the functionality we made different micro services.

Now we are blocked with one point.

Apart from different Actors we have "administration" or "customer service" users.

From them , we have some specific APIS.

We have a questions around this.

```
1) Do we need to consider creating different micro service project.
2) Assume we consider different micro services, do we need to share all the domain models to this micro service.

3) Assume, we keep Admin or Customer Service APIS in respective Micro services, how good it is. my point is about exposing or potential to expose Admin API to the world.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Do we need to consider creating different micro service project.

If your data makes sense to move to micro-service architecture, Yes, you should consider micro-services architecture.

> 3) Assume, we keep Admin or Customer Service APIS in respective Micro
>   services, how good it is. my point is about exposing or potential to
>   expose Admin API to the world

I am afraid that you are looking at this from a wrong angle. User's role should not be the one which drives the micro-service design. Instead it should be your data/entities/domains. Rule of thump is datastore should be different for different micro-services.

> 2) Assume we consider different micro services, do we need to share
>   all the domain models to this micro service.

I wanted to answer this after the above one. If you design your micro-services right, your domain overlap will be minimal, in turn the code (domain POJOs) that need to be shared will be minimal, but still it's not totally avoidable. There are some creative ways to share the code

1. publish a library jar file with all the shared code to your internal repo and refer it in your main projects
2. Have a parent project which will have all your micro-services, so that you can share the code. ( Congrats, you just created a monolithic codebase :) ) In all seriousness, IMHO, this is against the spirit of micro-services. Even though you still can deploy each of your micro-services as separate application/jar files, the codebase is still monolithic)

A small piece of advice is, just don't get hung up on code share-ability. What if you decide to use a non-JVM language like go/rust to write your other micro-services. After all, that is one of the main selling point of a micro service architecture.

Comment: I totally agree with you. One small question bugging my head. Every application have customer facing and our customer service facing.  I understand some of the work is done only by Customer Service in the same domain area where customer is doing.  Now Those work which are done at the customer service level at same domain of customer . Do you think those APIS goes in same micro service as customer. Reason why I am asking because, if we want add additional security level at customer service level and/or scale up Customer facing services, this become little tricky.

Comment: @Kumar..  Microservice architecture is just one of the software architecture out there (which happened to get some buzz lately). This is an era of Functions as a service (Serverless/AWS lambda). And some people are even going back to the Monolithic architecture https://segment.com/blog/goodbye-microservices/, https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17499137 . You have to choose what deems more fit into your usecase, There is no right or wrong answer here.

Comment: If you think spinning off the admin functionality as a separate service will give you more flexibility and inherent-security, what's stopping you, you can always justify your choice.

Comment: I should accept this. Yes, we should definitely go with the requirements, rather than new buzz words.